# How to use Formik with array of objects inside an object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik, react-typescript

I have an object like this:

```
Vehicle {
    string VIN;
    ...
    Number[] Numbers;
}

Number {
    string type;
    string sequence;
}
```

I want to use this data in an editable layout in my frontend [React + Typescript].
So far I'm doing pretty well with parameters like VIN:

```
<Formik
    initialValues={props.values}
    onSubmit={(values: VehicleDetailFields, actions: FormikActions<VehicleDetailFields>) => {
        props.handleSubmit(values);
    }}
    enableReinitialize={true}
>
    {(formikProps: FormikProps<VehicleDetailFields>) => {
        return (
            <div className={css.vehicleDetails}>
                <Form>
                    <h1>
                        {t('vehicles:details.title1')}
                    </h1>
                    <div className={css.detailsArea}>
                        <Field
                            placeholder={t('vehicles:details.interpoL_STATUS')}
                            name="interpoL_STATUS_Description"
                            component={TextInput}
                            value={formikProps.values.interpoL_STATUS_Description}
                            disabled
                        />
...
```

So far I've tried the following using `<FieldArray>`. I am able to print the data, but I can't edit the fields. I suppose it's because of the "name" property on `<Field>` but I can't figure the correct way of solving it.

```
<FieldArray
    name="formikProps.values.smvNumbers"
    render={(arrayHelpers) => (
        <div>
            {formikProps.values.smvNumbers && formikProps.values.smvNumbers.length > 0 ?
                (
                    formikProps.values.smvNumbers.map((currentNumber, index) => (
                        <Field
                            placeholder="teste"
                            name={currentNumber}
                            component={TextInput}
                            value={currentNumber.sequence}
                            hidden={false}
                        />
                    ))
                ) : ''
            }
        </div>
    )}
/>
```

If there is any other alternative I am open to hear them out.

Comment: `FieldArray` should have a name provided that is a property path of an array relative to the provided `initialValues`, `Field` should have a name provided that is a property path relative to the provided `initialValues`. What this means is that if you provided `initialValues` a value of `{ addresses: [{ country: 'Country A'}, { country: 'Country B'}] }` and want to use `addresses` with `FieldArray` you would provided the name "addresses", if you want to have an input for the second addresses' country you would provide the `Field` the name "addresses[1].country".